# Display html text without html malform

Tags: html, special-characters, html-escape-characters, malformed

I have a button name with a special character `>` . It displays fines but there is a malformed html when I check the console in the browser.

```
<button type="submit"> Submit> </button>
```

What I want is this, display `>` with the button name and in the same time if I inspect html elements I want it to show as `&gt;`.

Is there a way to escape it? It tried using the taglibrary (JSTL fn:escapeXml()) but didn't work.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you for the time

Comment: `&gt;` can be used to display `>` http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: @redditor i tried that but when inspect the element it shows '>'

Comment: In your question you write: _if i inspect html elements i want it to show as >_. In your comment above, you write: _when [... I...] inspect the element it shows '>'_. Can you explain further what is happening that isn't working properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As [@redditor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045794/redditor) mentioned in a comment, you may use the HTML name `&gt;`, or you can use `&#62` which is the HTML number for it.

Some symbols which are used in HTML markup or others which we can't type them are represented as HTML entities and HTML numbers.

See it in action [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8fm7k77h/1/) - *updated to include the button*

**Examples**

- © = `&copy;`
- » = `&raquo;`
- « = `&laquo;`
- £ = `&pound;`
- ¼ = `&frac14;`

**Resource:**

- http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm
- http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp

Answer (score -1):

I would have tried using PHP.

```
 <?php
 echo "<button type=\"submit\"> Submit\> </button>";
 ?>
```

Comment: `\"submit\"` ... `'submit'` also... what's this \  in `Submit\>`? It'll end up as a literal `\>`

Comment: actually you can write the line above without escaping using outer single quotes like this  `echo '<button type="submit"> Submit > </button>';` [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zzyt-terp) *hit run or F9 to see result*